# reverse function with 2 unknowns

Tags: c#, bit-shift

I'm having some difficulty reversing the following functions done before storing data to a device.

```
ss = enum + 16
u32ts = number << 8
u32timestamp = ss+u32ts
```

`enum` and `number` are the two vaules I'm trying to get back but I'm unawaire of what either of them are when I start with `u32timestamp`.

What I have tried to do is

```
uint temp = u32timestamp;
number  = 0;
if (u32timestamp > 100)
{
   number  = (u32timestamp >> 8 & 8 );
   temp = u32timestamp - number ;
}
enum = temp - 16;
```

But I keep getting out the incorrect values. Please help me fix this. `enum` is always between 16 and 21 but `number` can be positive any value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a = u32timestamp&0xFF;
var number= u32timestamp >>8;
var en = a-16;
```

the coding place "number" shifting eight bit to the left, so a regular 8 shift on the right will recover it by trashing the LS bits. Then we mask the lower bit to recover en.

Answer (score 2):

```
// sample a and b
int a = 5, b = 7;

int ss = a + 16;
int u32ts = b << 8;
int u32timestamp = ss + u32ts;

// reversing...
int rev_b = u32timestamp >> 8;
int rev_ss = u32timestamp - (rev_b << 8);
int rev_a = rev_ss - 16;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void Decode
{
   uint u32timestamp = 31778;
   var number = u32timestamp >> 8;
   var temp = u32timestamp - (number << 8);
   var en  = temp - 16;
}
```